# Rust generic struct with a trait including lifetime - how to produce trait-objects from an external method

Tags: generics, rust, lifetime

Rust Play-example: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=f795cd150774a61e8580c602c7f4e0f4

I've got a decoder, that will produce items of type MESSAGE (trait). I'd like to make the decoder generic, so that ideally I can produce MESSAGE's with correct type without specifying the type later on.

Defining decoder:

```rust
use std::marker::PhantomData;

struct Decoder<MESSAGE> {
    _phantom: PhantomData<MESSAGE>,
}

impl<MESSAGE> Decoder<MESSAGE> {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        Decoder {
            _phantom: PhantomData::default(),
        }
    }
    
    pub fn decode_message_from_buffer<'a, 'b>(&'b self, buffer: &'a mut [u8]) -> MESSAGE where MESSAGE: MessageType<'a> {
        MESSAGE::from(buffer)
    }
}
```

Defining the trait

```rust
trait MessageType<'a> {
    fn from(buffer: &'a mut [u8]) -> Self;
}
```

Creating a message `ApiMessage` that implements the MessageType (MESSAGE) trait.

```rust
struct ApiMessage<'a> {
    _slice: &'a [u8]
}

impl<'a> MessageType<'a> for ApiMessage<'a> {
    fn from(buffer: &'a mut [u8]) -> Self {
        ApiMessage {
            _slice: &buffer[..5]
        }
    }
}
```

Now the main loop, where i first initialize the decoder (with expected MESSAGE[type] = ApiMessage). Then I initialize buffer, that is needed for decoding.

If I call the decoder method directly (second example inside loop), it works.

But with a helper method (that's needed for other logic), I get an error about buffer not living long enough.

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut decoder: Decoder<ApiMessage> = Decoder::new();
    
    // if the buffer is moved inside while-loop, error is "borrowed value does not live long enough"
    let mut buffer = [0u8; 1024];

    for _ in 0..5 {
        // ERROR: can't borrow buffer in a loop
        let _message = decode_with_decoder(&mut decoder, &mut buffer);
        
        // however, this works
        // let _message = decoder.decode_message_from_buffer(&mut buffer);
    }
}
```

Here's the helper method.

```rust
fn decode_with_decoder<'a, MESSAGE>(decoder: &mut Decoder<MESSAGE>, buffer: &'a mut [u8]) -> MESSAGE
    where MESSAGE: MessageType<'a>
{
    decoder.decode_message_from_buffer(buffer)
}
```

I believe that the failure is caused by MESSAGE in the above definition refering to `Decoder<MESSAGE>` (with life time 'a, which is the lifetime of decoder struct), and also to the return result MESSAGE, where the same lifetime is used.

Is there a way to decouple the lifetimes of the MESSAGE-type in Decoder struct, and produced MESSAGE's of `decode_with_decoder`?

Comment: Does the reference to the `Decoder` in `decode_with_decoder()` really have to be mutable? Rust doesn't assume that you might keep a reference to `buffer` in `decoder` if it's immutable.